# Regex - how to include URL, up to non-alphabet characters or certain characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regex that captures the handle of Twitter account.
For example if URL is https://twitter.com/example, I want to capture "example".

I was able to do so with this: (?<=twitter.com.)(.*)

However there is an issue, if other characters come after it.

For example if the URL is :
https://twitter.com/example/ or
https://twitter.com/example?abc=xyz

Now it captures / and everything after ? as well.

How can I capture just the handle, and stop when there are invalid characters?
There can be _ in the handle as well, so _ cannot stop the regex.

Hope that makes sense.. Thank you in advance.

(?<=twitter.com.)(.*)

I wanted to capture just the Twitter handle, but it also captures other characters such as "/" or "?abc=xyz"

Comment: If only there was one universal regex, this would be a good question, but many systems and languages have their own unique regex expressions.  Without knowing what language(s) or utilities you are using, this question really can't be accurately answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .* is too greedy. You need to be more specific or excluding ([^...]) the parameters in general:

(?<=twitter.com.)([^?]*)

I think the above does what you wanted.